# php not inserting data into table

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a HTML form

```
<div class="contact-form col-md-6 " >
                <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="" role="form">

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Your Email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Your Phone Number" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" required>
                    </div>                  
                    <div class="response_msg"></div>
                    <div id="mail-success" class="success">
                        Thank you. You are registerd. :)
                    </div>

                    <div id="mail-fail" class="error">
                        Sorry, don't know what happened. Try later :(
                    </div>

                    <div id="cf-submit">
        <input type="submit" id="contact-submit" class="btn btn-transparent" value="Register" name="submit">
                    </div>                                          
                </form>
            </div>
```

I need to submit form on same page and show message on successfully submission. I am using JS for this

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#contact-form").on("submit",function(e){
e.preventDefault();
if($("#contact-form [name='name']").val() === '')
{
$("#contact-form [name='name']").css("border","1px solid red");
}
else if ($("#contact-form [name='email']").val() === '')
{
$("#contact-form [name='email']").css("border","1px solid red");
}
else if ($("#contact-form [name='phone']").val() === '')
{
$("#contact-form [name='phone']").css("border","1px solid red");
}
else
{
$("#loading-img").css("display","block");
var sendData = $( this ).serialize();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "js/ajaxsubmit.php",
data: sendData,
success: function(data){
$("#loading-img").css("display","none");
$(".response_msg").text(data);
$(".response_msg").slideDown().fadeOut(3000);
$("#contact-form").find("input[type=text], input[type=email], textarea").val("");
}

});
}
});

$("#contact-form input").blur(function(){
var checkValue = $(this).val();
if(checkValue != '')
{
$(this).css("border","1px solid #eeeeee");
}
});
});
</script>
```

As soon i clicked on submit button page refresh but my i don't see my pho code inserting data in database.

```
<?php 
require_once("conn.php");
if((isset($_POST['name'])&& $_POST['name'] !='') && (isset($_POST['email'])&& $_POST['email'] !='') && (isset($_POST['phone'])&& $_POST['phone'] !=''))
{
// require_once("contact_mail.php");

    $yourName = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $yourEmail = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $yourPhone = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
    $sql="INSERT INTO Beta_Registration (name, email, phone) VALUES ('".$yourName."','".$yourEmail."', '".$yourPhone."')";
    if(!$result = $conn->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $conn->error . ']');
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Thank you! We will contact you soon";
    }
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Please fill Name and Email";
    }
    ?>
```

I want my form to submit on same page also stays on same block and shows the messages in `div` inside form when data entered successfully or failed into database.

The issues i am facing whenever i press submit button it refreshed the page and form data doesn't executed into database. It might be php or JS i am using. Please help me in this.

Comment: Start by replacing the submit input to a button. That's what mostly used when dealing with JS inputs/forms.

Comment: I don't get it. Can you please elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- You need to add "return false" in your on submit function to prevent browser to submit the form

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#contact-form").on("submit", function (e) {
        ...
        return false;
    });
    ...
});
```

2- You need to match you database table name, and their columns name which you have used in your MySQL query.

Comment: this is not working. Data not inserting into database have perfect match into database table and columns

Comment: Try to use this code to debug the error, your SQL query seems fine but MySQL may have been throwing some error which you may get with this code. You may also check that your table have primary key and is it set to auto increment?
$result = $conn->query($sql);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($conn);
    exit;